# How to align a background image with buttons in windows forms (Visual Studio)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, windows-forms-designer

Basically I want to have 4 buttons inside a circle. I didn't find a tool to draw a circle so I thought I could paint the circle with Paint, and then put that image as a background, and then overlay my buttons, something like this:
[image]

The blue circle and the blue rectangle are a background image of my form application.

[image]

My form is 1280*720 and the image I use as background is also 1280*720. 
However, when I run the app, everything moves out of its place:

[image]

As you can see, the 4 buttons moved out of the circle.

Question is: why are they moving outside the circle if both the form app and my background img are 1280*720 px.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be a good practice to learn how to use C#'s graphics system. For this project you'd probably want to draw an ellipse (read about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawellipse?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads)) and then play around with its size and position until you get it where it needs to be. Or if you're committed to still using paint it'd be best to just import the image of the circle to a `PictureBox` and then positioning that as needed.